# Setup Chakra UI in Next.js's new app folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, chakra-ui

I am trying to use Chakra UI `v2.4.9` with my Next.js `v13.1.6` following the [the Chakra UI step-up guide with Next.js](https://chakra-ui.com/getting-started/nextjs-guide), but it doesn't work.

I am using the `src/` folder which contains `app/` and `pages/`. as the [provider step up](https://chakra-ui.com/getting-started/nextjs-guide) says I created the `_app.js` file with the following content

```
// src/_app.js

import { ChakraProvider } from '@chakra-ui/react'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <ChakraProvider>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </ChakraProvider>
  )
}

export default MyApp
```

Then I tried to use Chakra elements in my `src/app/page.js` as follows:

```
"use client"
import Image from 'next/image'
import { Inter } from '@next/font/google'
import styles from './page.module.css'
import { Button } from '@chakra-ui/react'

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export default function Home() {
  return <div>
    <h1>Hello Chakra UI</h1>
    <Button colorScheme={"red"}>CLICK ME</Button>
  </div>
}
```

It shows the button without any style, Not like the Chakra UI `Button` with the red color scheme.

I thought the issue was the `_app.js` file location that it is currently in `src/_app.js` and tried putting the file at

- `/_app.js` at the project root
- `/src/_app.js` root of src folder (current)
- `/src/pages/_app.js` as the Chakra UI docs says
- `/src/app/_app.js`

And it is still not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like the Chakra documentation only warned about the `app` directory, and the other part is for the `pages` folder, like in older versions. To use any context in the `app` folder, I suggest you read the [context](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/rendering/server-and-client-components#context) part of the new doc. Following that, you would do it like so:

```js
// app/theme-provider.js 

'use client';

import { ChakraProvider } from '@chakra-ui/react'

export default function ThemeProvider({ children }) {
  return (
    <ChakraProvider>
      {children}
    </ChakraProvider >
  );
}
```

```js
// app/layout.js 

import ThemeProvider from './theme-provider';

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html>
      <body>
        <ThemeProvider>{children}</ThemeProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

```
// app/page.js 

"use client";

import { Button } from "@chakra-ui/react";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello Chakra UI</h1>
      <Button colorScheme={"red"}>CLICK ME</Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```